# Programmatic configuration of Exception-sending in WCF

Tags: wcf, wcf-behaviour

I would like my Silverlight client to be able to display exceptions that have happened at the server during a WCF call.

Given my current code to create a WCF Channel (on the client):

```
// create the binding elements
BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement binaryMessageEncoding = new BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement();
HttpTransportBindingElement httpTransport = new HttpTransportBindingElement() { MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue, MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue };

// add the binding elements into a Custom Binding
CustomBinding customBinding = new CustomBinding(binaryMessageEncoding, httpTransport);

// create the Endpoint URL 
EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(serviceUrl);

            // create an interface for the WCF service
ChannelFactory<TWcfApiEndPoint> channelFactory=new ChannelFactory<TWcfApiEndPoint>(customBinding, endpointAddress);
channelFactory.Faulted += new EventHandler(channelFactory_Faulted);         
TWcfApiEndPoint client = channelFactory.CreateChannel();

return client;
```

When an exception occurs, I just get a "NotFound" exception, which is obviously of no use. How can I get the exception information?

I use this code to use the client object returned above:

```
try
{
// customFieldsBroker is the client returned above
        customFieldsBroker.BeginCreateCustomField(DataTypeID, newCustomField, (result) =>
        {
            var response = ((ICustomFieldsBroker)result.AsyncState).EndCreateCustomField(result);

    }, customFieldsBroker);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // would like to handle exception here
}
```

Wrapping the Begin/End calls in a try { } catch { } block doesn't seem to even jump into the catch { } block.

If it matters, I'm using Silverlight 3 at the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to security limitations in the browser sandbox, silverlight can't see the body of server errors (status code 500). To get this working you need to make a change to the server side, to change the way it returns faults to the browser. There's an [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470096(VS.95).aspx) that describes it in detail.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. This has solved it.

Although, I'm concerned about the web.config setting requirement:

 <behaviorExtensions>
    <add name="silverlightFaults"
      type="IWW.MIGTurbo2.WCF.SilverlightFaultBehavior, IWW.MIGTurbo2.WCF, Version=2.0.0.429, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
   </behaviorExtensions>

I seem to have have the complete Version= there, which I would like to avoid, as it is dynamically updated. Is there a way I can ignore this version number?

Comment: I _think_ it will still bind the type without the full name. What happens if you take out the Version?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things:

- declare the Fault exception as part of the contract
- throw the exception as a fault exception

  [OperationContract]

  [FaultContract(typeof(ArithmeticFault))]

  public int Calculate(Operation op, int a, int b)

  {
       // ...
   }

  throw new FaultException();